# Angular $scope has push() as undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my HTML:

```
<input ng-blur="CheckUser()" name="username" ng-model="RegisterFormData.username"
                                           class="form-control"/>{{ a.check_username_result }}
```

The controller and ng-app are assigned, since every part of the application is working and the only missing part is that I cannot send back data after `$http` request to the page, it says property of `push()` is undefined

Now, here is my controller and `CheckUser()` is the event which sends a certain data back to the page after some operation, though all operations are done properly, except the push() which errors as undefined:

```
LoginApp.controller("RegisterController", function($scope, $http, registerService){
    var username  = null;
    var password = null;

    RegisterData = $scope.RegisterFormData;

    $scope.CheckUser = function(RegisterData){

        username = $scope.RegisterFormData.username;
        console.log(username);
        usernameResult = registerService.CheckUser(username);


        if( usernameResult == "exists")
            $scope.a.push({check_username_result : "Username already exists, Choose another."});
        else if( usernameResult == 'fresh')
            $scope.a.push({check_username_result : "Username available!"});
        else
            $scope.a.push({check_username_result : "Error. try again."});
    }; // end of user_check()

    $scope.registerSubmit  = function(){
        username = $scope.RegisterFormData.username;
        password = $scope.RegisterFormData.password;


    };
});
```

Comment: Well, first question is what the heck is `$scope.a`, and where does it get defined? Did you simply forget to initialize it as an array, or is defined somewhere else (like, inherited from `$rootScope`)?

Comment: That's exactly what I was just wondering, @HackedByChinese

Comment: Learning JavaScript before AngularJS would help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just declare `$scope.a` as an array, then you can push to it.

```
$scope.a = [];
$scope.CheckUser = function(RegisterData){
// ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call functions on an object before it it defined. You can do

```
$scope.a=[];
```

And then

```
$scope.a.push({check_username_result : "Username already exists, Choose another."});
```